# VBA formula from one workbook to another with named cells

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I can't get my formula to work. You can see that I am simply trying to subtract one value (there is a formula in the cells) from another from one workbook to another. What am I missing? It copies the formula in the correct cell but does not calculate. Results #NAME?.

```
Sub changeReports()
    Dim currentWk As Worksheet
    Dim prevYr As Worksheet
    Dim prevWk As Worksheet
    Dim File_Path As String
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_workbook As Workbook

    File_Path = "B:\Operations\Aging 031416Wk11.xlsm"
    Destination_Path = "B:\Operations\Aging 032116Wk12.xlsm"
    Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File_Path)
    Set Target_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Destination_Path)
    Set prevWk = Source_Workbook.Worksheets("2016 Reports")
    Set currentWk = Target_workbook.Worksheets("2016 Reports")       
    currentWk.Activate  

    ' code works to insert formula in cell but formula not working the way    it is written
    Range("chgBox").formula = "=currentWk.Range(""grBox"")- prevWk.Range(""grBox"")"     
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider reconstructing the question to show code in a more readable format and give examples of your inputs with your expected results contrasted to the results you are getting instead.

Comment: @DanielGraham - I think I just did that. the first time it was a mess. I can edit to give examples results but it would be just a number (value).

Comment: Ahh, gotchya, I see that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the result of the subtraction in the  Range("chgBox") cell then performthe actual calculation.

```
Range("chgBox") = currentWk.Range("grBox") - prevWk.Range("grBox")
```

If you want the formula to remain in the  Range("chgBox") cell then convert the VBA cell references to addresses and concatenate a string that will represent the worksheet formula.

```
Range("chgBox").Formula = "=" & currentWk.Range("grBox").Address(external:=true) & _
                            "-" & prevWk.Range("grBox").Address(external:=true)
```

You were getting the `#NAME!` error because the worksheet doesn't understand what `currentWk.Range(""grBox"")` is.

Addendum:

I've run through a full sample testing environment and both the formula and direct result work as provided above. I've cleaned up the remainder of the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub changeReports()
    Dim currentWk As Worksheet
    Dim prevWk As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String, destinationPath As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, targetWorkbook As Workbook

    filePath = "B:\Operations\Aging 031416Wk11.xlsm"
    destinationPath = "B:\Operations\Aging 032116Wk12.xlsm"
    filePath = Environ("TMP") & "\Aging 031416Wk11.xlsm"
    destinationPath = Environ("TMP") & "\Aging 032116Wk12.xlsm"

    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(destinationPath)
    Set prevWk = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("2016 Reports")
    Set currentWk = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("2016 Reports")

    With currentWk
        .Range("chgBox") = .Range("grBox") - prevWk.Range("grBox")
        '.Range("chgBox").Formula = "=" & currentWk.Range("grBox").Address & _
                            "-" & prevWk.Range("grBox").Address(external:=True)
    End With

    sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    targetWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I want the result of the calculation. I tried that and I get the error: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: I hadn't noticed the double quotes in the Range objects with the named range's names and had to edit them out after my original post. Did you use the later revision? What happens then you put `currentWk.Range("grBox").Address(external:=true)` and `debug.print prevWk.Range("grBox").Address(external:=true)` before the calculation? What is reported i the Immediate window? What does the Locals window say about the ranges? Have you set a Watch on the named range values?

Comment: OMG @Jeeped I feel like such an idiot! I have been struggling with this again all morning. My original code worked. Range("chgBox") = .Range("grBox") - prevWk.Range("grBox") I forgot to name the cells in the prevWk. Rookie mistake! I am a beginner but that was just dumb. Thanks again for you help.